# Unusual appearance when scrolling UITableView with custom cells and selection status

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview containing custom cells, which override `setSelected:animated:`. Sometimes, when scrolling the table containing selected cells, the appearance of the selected cells is a strange mix of the selected and unselected state.

My `setSelected:animated:` method looks like this:

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (selected == self.selected)
        return;

    CGFloat destinationAlpha = selected ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    NSTimeInterval duration = animated ? 0.25 : 0.0;

    for (UIView *view in self.topView.subviews)
    {
        if (![self.viewsToLeaveBackgroundAlone containsObject:view])
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.selectedTopViewBackground.alpha = destinationAlpha;
    }animations completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (!selected)
        {
            for (UIView *view in self.topView.subviews)
            {
                if (![self.viewsToLeaveBackgroundAlone containsObject:view])
                    view.backgroundColor = self.topView.backgroundColor;
            }
        }        
    }];

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

I've added logs and breakpoints and right cell is getting the right selected status sent to it. What can be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can't rely on the completion blocks of zero-duration animations to be called immediately, which makes sense when you think about it. From my testing, the completed parameter is always `YES` as well.

Though it is very tempting to simply set a duration of zero for transitions that are not supposed to be animated, if the animation contains a completion block and the method is called in quick succession, you can't guarantee the order that the completion blocks are called in.

For example, whilst scrolling a table up and down, the following can happen:

- A selected cell is scrolled off the screen and re-used (selected:NO animated:NO)
- The selected cell is scrolled back onto the screen (selected:YES animated:NO)

Using zero length animations doesn't guarantee that the completion block from the first call is called before the completion block from the second call.

A solution is to wrap the animation operations and completion operations in two local blocks, and execute these directly or pass to the animation, depending on the `animated` parameter:

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if (selected == self.selected)
        return;

    CGFloat destinationAlpha = selected ? 1.0 : 0.0;

    for (UIView *view in self.topView.subviews)
    {
        if (![self.viewsToLeaveBackgroundAlone containsObject:view])
            view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    dispatch_block_t animations = ^{
        self.selectedTopViewBackground.alpha = destinationAlpha;
    };

    dispatch_block_t completion = ^{
        if (!selected)
        {
            for (UIView *view in self.topView.subviews)
            {
                if (![self.viewsToLeaveBackgroundAlone containsObject:view])
                    view.backgroundColor = self.topView.backgroundColor;
            }
        }
    };

    if (animated)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:animations completion:^(BOOL finished) { completion();}];
    }
    else
    {
        animations();
        completion();
    }
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

This has the additional advantage (for more complex cases) of not having one massive call containing two huge blocks of code. Even more so if you have nested animations.